# missing some feature in xcode IDE (xcode)

Tags: xcode

in one of my project some feature are missing, like selection segure & w any & h any in bottom of xcode
do you know how to fix it?
   thanks

[image: this is project picture]

Comment: @Bhavin thanks Bhavin, its work. thanks alot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to enable sizeClasses for that bottom panel ..

Here are the steps:

1. In the project navigator, select a storyboard or xib file.
2. Choose View > Utilities > Show File Inspector.
3. In the Interface Builder Document section, select the Use Size Classes checkbox.

For more info. check [this link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_adaptive_sizes/chapters/EnablingAdaptiveSizeDesign.html)